# Does `delete <pointer>` destroy only the pointer, or also the pointee?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management

In C++ we always have to `delete` a pointer after we `new`ed it.

But I'm trying to understand if that simply deletes the pointer, or also calls the destructor of the *pointed to* object.

For example:

```
Thing* pointer = new Thing;
// .. some code
delete pointer;
```

Does this call the destructor of the object pointed to by `pointer`? Or does it only destory the pointer?

Comment: That is misleading. You don't delete pointers, you delete what it points to. (Although I may talk that way informally..) The pointer in your example is on the stack. It is just like an int. The following is valid, but pointless: `delete new int;` LOL the pun wasn't intended.

Comment: Just for completeness: You also don't "new" a pointer. You declare a pointer and then you initialise it with the address of the Thing you newed (look where the "new" is in your code: it's in front of the Thing and you could even assign the result to pointer on the next line, if you want). So it makes perfect sense that you don't delete the pointer itself, either, because symmetry is always aesthetically pleasing ;)

Comment: If you're learning C++ for the first time now it would be best to start using smart pointers straight away. "If you're typing 'delete' you're doing it wrong".

Answer (score 6):

> Does this call the destructor of the object referenced by `pointer`?

Yes, it destroys the object by calling its destructor. It also deallocates the memory that `new` allocated to store the object.

> Or does it only destory the pointer?

It does nothing to the pointer. That still exists, but no longer points to a valid object, so can't be used until you assign a valid pointer value to it.

Comment: If a deallocation function is called, it invalidates the pointer, making it implementation-defined behavior to even attempt to use the value of the pointer (without dereferencing).

Comment: @T.C. Only implementation-defined and not undefined? What alternative could an implementation define for it?

Comment: @NeilKirk Dereferencing or passing to a deallocation function is still UB. Doing anything else (even just copying the value of the pointer) is implementation defined.

Comment: @T.C.: No, it's undefined. See C++11 3.7.4.2/4: "The effect of using an invalid pointer value [...] is undefined."

Comment: @MikeSeymour So it changed between C++11 and C++14 (I was looking at N3936). The same paragraph now reads "Indirection through an invalid pointer value and passing an invalid pointer value to a deallocation function have undefined behavior. Any other use of an invalid pointer value has implementation-defined behavior." See [CWG 1438](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1438).

Comment: @T.C.: OK then. But none of this is particularly relevant to the question; it's invalid, so don't use it.